# How can I find different GPIO pins address in ti-rtos?

Tags: gpio, rtos

I want to develop a simple test for gpio in ti-rtos. An example for gpio driver exists in sdk install directory but it uses GPIO_USER_LEDx ports for writing to gpio. How to use another gpio pins in GPIO_write function?

I used gpios in linux program before but i don't know the address register of gpios in ti-rtos.

Comment: It is not about the RTOS, to advise we would have to know the the specific part you are using, and even then you would likely simply be directed to the reference manual/datasheet.  In Linux the GPIO driver is an abstraction, in this case you are talking directly to the hardware an the RTOS is largely irrelevant and not involved.  GPIO_USER_LEDx is likely a macro for your board; the MCU does not have GPIO specific to LED control - take a look at its definition.

Comment: this is a part of example code in TI RTOS SDK that define this macro:


/************************************************/
typedef enum GPIO_USER_LED {
    GPIO_USER_LED0 = 0,
    GPIO_USER_LED1
}GPIO_LED;
/**********************************************/

i can't understand a general way for defining GPIOS from it.

Comment: You should ask a question about that and include code or a link to the SDK.  The answer will be in how that enumeration is used.  Despite the name, they are clearly not GPIO addresses, most likely they are used in a lookup or switch to get the GPIO register address somewhere.  Surely if you have an SDK there is documentation. If you indicate specifically what you are using you will get better help TI-RTOS is too vague, TI produce that for multiple target devices.  Moreover the example you posted looks like it is example code, and not part of the SDK itself.

Comment: ... and update the question with the requested information, do not try to add code or extend the question in the comments.  SO is a Q&A not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Reference Manual for your particular microcontroller and review the section about GPIO.  The reference manual should explain all the GPIO registers and the base address of the GPIO registers.  The microcontroller's Datasheet explains further which GPIO ports are available and how those ports are mapped to physical pins on a particular microcontroller.

The GPIO_USER_LEDx definitions in your SDK project are likely specific to the board you are working with.  Compare the GPIO_USER_LEDx definitions with the schematic for the board (pin numbers) and the microcontroller's Datasheet and Reference Manual.  This will help you understand the Datasheet and Reference Manual by giving you a concrete example of how the information in those documents was applied to your board.

TI-RTOS is a real-time operating system and not really comparable to a general purpose operating system such as Linux.  Typically, an RTOS is not necessary and not significant to controlling GPIO on a microcontroller.

Comment: I should use a RTOS for main project and using GPIO is part of it, but TI has only a RTOS User Guide that there isn't any information about GPIOs address and the way for writing to specific a GPIO in it.

Comment: @MFSakht Yes, there isn't any information about GPIOs in the TI-RTOS User Guide because the RTOS is not relevant or applicable to GPIO control.  GPIO can be controlled without the RTOS.  You have to refer to the microcontroller's Reference Manual and Datasheet for information about the GPIO.